# Dividend paying asset, why can't be taken as numéraire?

Tags: risk-neutral-measure, numerairechange

Why when considering numéraires, one cannot use a dividend paying asset to define a risk neutral measure?

Here's where I got my question : (Shreve - Stochastic Calculus For Finance II)

[image]

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean. A dividend paying asset $S_t$ (such as a stock) *can* be used to define an equivalent pricing measure $\Bbb{Q}^S$ under which prices of self-financing strategies - when expressed into the stock numéraire - are martingales. It's actually one way of obtaining the $N(d_1)$ term in the BS formula and interpreting it as $\Bbb{Q}^S(S_T > K)$ (while $N(d_2)$ is $\Bbb{Q}^B(S_T > K)$ where $B_t$ is the risk-free money market account hence $\Bbb{Q}^B$ the risk-neutral measure).

Comment: The only caveat IMO is that a numéraire should be a traded asset with an always positive price (which is OK under the dividend yield extension of BS, but needs greater care when dividends are discrete and fixed rather than proportional).

Comment: Thank you. I edited my post with what's in Shreve's book. So if you say that you can define a measure with respect to $S$ paying a dividend, you mean that you can find a that measure but it's not a risk neutral one?